# Saving portions of a Google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

As I'm developping an application for hikers, I want to be able to store, somewhere in the device memory, the portion of the map where the user will travel. This is necessary because those places are generally out of any network reach.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: You might be able to make use of [“Download map area” added to Labs in Google Maps for Android](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/download-map-area-added-to-labs-in.html) in July this year.

Comment: OK, Google maps can do it via the lab. But how can I use this feature in my own application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not alowed under the google licence so you should not even look at trying.

You could use another mapping source e.g. [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).  There is an android Library [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) that I have managed to get to work.  With this you can legaly cache the tiles.  As for how to get them I have not implemented that yet but if the user looks at the area of interest first manualy it is just working for me.

Somthing cleverer will take more work but should be possible.